# Why is the GST for the wholesaler based on the marked price? We don't know if that is the cost price.

Tags: economics

The price of a sewing machine is Rs.40000.The wholesaler allows a discount of 10% on it to the shopkeeper. The shopkeeper sells the sewing machine to a customer at a discount of 5% on the marked price. GST is charged at the rate of 28% .The sales are intra-state.
Find the GST paid by the wholesaler to the state government.

A lot of sites are telling me that the SGST paid by the wholesaler is Rs. 5600

[image: Image of answer]

But that doesn't make any sense. Firstly, we don't know if the cost price of the article is Rs 40000. That is just the marked price. Realistically, the wholesaler bought it at a slightly lower price (let's say Rs 35000), and marked it up to Rs 40,000. Secondly, even if we were to take the cost price as Rs 40,000 (which is wrong in my opinion), the SGST paid by the wholesaler would be 14/100*(40000 - 36000) which is Rs 560.

Ideally, the GST for the wholesaler should be taken on the selling price, as that is the only concrete information we have. So it should be 14/100*36000 = Rs 5040. So how is the answer still Rs 5600?

Comment: That Expert Answer is wrong : GST must be on Selling Price ! [ https://byjus.com/question-answer/on-what-is-goods-and-service-tax-gst-levied-cost-price-selling-price-marked-price-1/ ] [ https://www.bankbazaar.com/tax/gst-calculator.html#:~:text=Example%20of%20GST%20Calculation,2,000%20=%20Rs. ]

Comment: In Australia the retailer pays GST on the selling price and claims back GST on the cost price. The wholesaler pays GST based on the wholesale price, which is the retailer's cost price.

Comment: There is no retailer here. I'm assuming you mean shopkeeper. What you are saying is correct. The wholesaler should pay GST based on the shopkeeper's cost price. Yet he is supposed to pay it on the marked price of all things? Makes no sense.

Comment: It is logical to use Actuals ( Selling Price ) not Hypotheticals ( Some Price Printed or Marked up some where else ) in all cases. Even when there is some Service ( Eg taxi ) , there is no "Marked Price" , yet there is a "Selling Price" : I think GST on Selling Price is logical.